# Django redirects error when using Squid

Tags: django, https, squid

I having an Internal Server Error (500) when saving a microsite in my Django website. The error trace is the following (I changed some not relevant parts):

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/add/https, https://www.my.com/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/107195/ 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response 
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/admin.py", line 318, in wrapper 
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func 
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/adminsite.py", line 73, in inner 
return view(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/admin.py", line 377, in parse_path 
return callback(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/admin.py", line 318, in wrapper 
return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func 
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/adminsite.py", line 73, in inner 
return view(request, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/admin.py", line 350, in parse_path 
basecontent = self._get_base_content(request, object_id) 
File "/var/www/django/mywebsite/myapp/base/admin.py", line 468, in _get_base_content 
obj = model.objects.get(pk=unquote(object_id)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method 
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 325, in get 
clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter 
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude 
clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1309, in add_q 
clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in _add_q 
allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq, 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1199, in build_filter 
lookups, value) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1751, in get_lookup_constraint 
lookup_class(target.get_col(alias, source), val), AND) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 101, in __init__ 
self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 139, in get_prep_lookup 
return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 727, in get_prep_lookup 
return self.get_prep_value(value) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value 
return int(value) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'add' 

Request repr(): 
<WSGIRequest 
path:/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/add/https, https://www.my.com/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/107195/, 
GET:<QueryDict: {}>, 
POST:<QueryDict: {}>, 
COOKIES:{'__atuvc': '0%7C1*****', 
'__atuvs': '593a635*******', 
'_ga': 'GA1.2.2144605537.147445****', 
'_gid': 'GA1.2.535445594.14970*****', 
'_pk_id.34.62bd': '9f289b5cc54e2ea4.1493721634.15.1497001551.1496998744.', 
'_pk_ref.34.62bd': '%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1496998744%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fdj.my.com%2FShibboleth.sso%2FSLO%2FRedirect%3FSAMLResponse%3DfZHRaoMwFIb*****************************hlyH%2FO%2F%2BXLZvvRNsE79Fg7mxMeMbItFhtUbdPJg3t1gz8Cds4iBGPSopyucjL0VjqFNUqrWkDptSzvHg4yjpjseueddg0J9rucPK8qphIWszDJIAs5h1W4ZmYZCi5isRSJSIUYo3YuOrlxyADL2AvXOhGGpUmiM8F5JlS1SlTK10sS7AB9bZWfwC%2FedygpNW%2FR0KoIkJaXuqpcA%2F4SITpaHh7pEUzdg%2FZjGeIAe4teWZ%2BTmPFVyETI0hOPZcwlz55IcJ6ljE8ixaRETnP9lYnbIhQi9F%2BApJgBa9PNhMqoEXPMxnRDr9YXP%2FpLr%2FyAf0%2F3zkBwVs0At5txSsty0BoQCS2%2BG36X0v%2B%2BuFh8Ag%3D%3D%26SigAlg%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1%26Signature%3DjbCQIhknc8YTRte2RgCK73aCs3mhvdtxcgswR0CKvfgFkEWybBs%2F1Vbu9VfzOwCA2FOIB%2F7e%2FdXh6st8owVoRmDWEYJMeoO%2FLTtRiUXB%2Be2h%2FyIZlBU4I40S22OIrj9NcNyfZrrckua2qGNmOzw7faRy9gmaMzCUaV%2BXWy65M5fWRdke%2Fix27yVBNx3jivRupUgK%2F1Kvd%2BUbPfXKPB%2FxI%2FL7J%2BNbPb06KD6oUc%2F4gHQy1zKZfOhnhqk922Umvj3Ek0zNaKP6%2FmwVUrBjibhklXFG%2B5
k6cRWglo 
rf0wH9r4%2F6yIfDJQl4ApEyJn1vGVztZJXMi1MY************************************aJHChZZLdRm9gW6WRWcPOJYvUHVVITDggkZ%2Bud%2FqmgjgYNB1pX%2FX%2BhWZYfsIonjeRd3bPdeh2C2zkBhM4ge07fQvvFd6Jmt7Uryvc68%22%5D',
'_pk_ses.34.62bd': '*', 
'_shibsession_64656661756c7468747470733a2f2f7777********************************': '_fc8c3ff27cf24**********************', 
'csrftoken': 'WURu5b7s6qie1HfZFwKuF8zTfu2RJz2x', 
'messages': '990eabc41b4402f5acd**********20b79078b004258$[["__json_message",0,25,"******************************************"]]', 
'sessionid': 'mxn2i399zj9c1com2vrqehsehye4jkjj'}, 
META:{'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, sdch', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8', 
'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0', 
'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close', 
'HTTP_COOKIE': '_pk_ref.34.62bd=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1496998744%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fdj.my.com%2FShibboleth.sso%2FSLO%2FRedirect%3FSAMLResponse%3DfZHRaoMwFIbv%**************************K0OTcQTxx5%2Fzk3WwehlyH%2FO%2F%2BXLZvvRNsE79Fg7mxMeMbItFhtUbdPJg3t1gz8Cds4iBGPSopyucjL0VjqFNUqrWkDptSzvHg4yjpjseueddg0J9rucPK8qphIWszDJIAs5h1W4ZmYZCi5isRSJSIUYo3YuOrlxyADL2AvXOhGGpUmiM8F5JlS1SlTK10sS7AB9bZWfwC%2FedygpNW%2FR0KoIkJaXuqpcA%2F4SITpaHh7pEUzdg%2FZjGeIAe4teWZ%2BTmPFVyETI0hOPZcwlz55IcJ6ljE8ixaRETnP9lYnbIhQi9F%2BApJgBa9PNhMqoEXPMxnRDr9YXP%2FpLr%2FyAf0%2F3zkBwVs0At5txSsty0BoQCS2%2BG36X0v%2B%2BuFh8Ag%3D%3D%26SigAlg%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1%26Signature%3DjbCQIhknc8YTRte2RgCK73aCs3mhvdtxcgswR0CKvfgFkEWybBs%2F1Vbu9VfzOwCA2FOIB%2F7e%2FdXh6st8owVoRmDWEYJMeoO%2FLTtRiUXB%2Be2h%2FyIZlBU4I40S22OIrj9NcNyfZrrckua2qGNmOzw7faRy9gmaMzCUaV%2BXWy65M5fWRdke%2Fix27yVBNx3jivRupUgK%2F1Kvd%2BUbPfXKPB%2FxI%2FL7J%2BNbPb06KD6oUc%2F4gHQy1zKZfOhnhqk922Umvj3Ek0zNaKP6%2FmwVUrBj
ibhklXFG 
%2B5k6cRWglorf0wH9r4%2F6yIfDJQl4ApEyJn1vGVztZJXMi1MYmBV8D3IRim7xm2wuogplwLfGi2CS7FHFaQns2SXjkpAXE9g0mjpotaJHChZZLdRm9gW6WRWcPOJYvUHVVIT*************************WZYfsIonjeRd3bPdeh2C2zkBhM4ge07fQvvFd6Jmt7Uryvc68%22%5D; _shibsession_64656661756c7468747470733a2f2f7777772e756d612e65732f73686962626f6c657468=_fc8c3ff27cf2489a0efde6d35c9b4c24; sessionid=mxn2i399zj9c1com2vrqehsehye4jkjj; _ga=GA1.2.2144605537.1474454489; _gid=GA1.2.535445594.1497001188; _pk_id.34.62bd=9f289b5cc54e2ea4.1493721634.15.1497001551.1496998744.; _pk_ses.34.62bd=*; __atuvc=0%7C19%2C0%7C20%2C0%7C21%2C0%7C22%2C45%7C23; __atuvs=593a6357c5bd8943004; csrftoken=WURu5b7s6qie1HfZFwKuF8zTfu2RJz2x; messages="990eabc41b4402f5ac4ca78ed20b79078b004258$[[\\"__json_message\\"\\0540\\05425\\054\\"Se a\\\\u00f1adi\\\\u00f3 con \\\\u00e9xito el evento \\\\\\"La evoluci\\\\u00f3n de los sistemas fiscales desde la Espa\\\\u00f1a medieval a la contempor\\\\u00e1nea: objetivos y consecuencias. Puede editarlo de nuevo abajo. 
\\"]]"', 
'HTTP_HOST': 'www.my.com', 
'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://www.my.com/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/add/', 
'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1', 
'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36', 
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '150.214.40.114', 
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT': '443', 
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'https, https', 
'PATH_INFO': u'/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/add/https, https://www.my.com/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/107195/', 
'QUERY_STRING': '', 
'REMOTE_ADDR': '192.168.24.185', 
'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 
'REQUEST_URI': '/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/add/https,%20https://www.my.com/admin/microsite/microsite/103271/event_section_admin/107195/',
'SCRIPT_NAME': u'', 
'SERVER_NAME': 'w7', 
'SERVER_PORT': '8000', 
'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1', 
'uwsgi.node': 'w7', 
'uwsgi.version': '2.0.14', 
'wsgi.errors': <open file 'wsgi_errors', mode 'w' at 0x504d8a0>, 
'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>, 
'wsgi.input': <uwsgi._Input object at 0xbe9fd50>, 
'wsgi.multiprocess': True, 
'wsgi.multithread': False, 
'wsgi.run_once': False, 
'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https, https', 
'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

I have noticed that REQUEST_URI have a malformed URL and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO have two protocols. This is only happening when accessing the site thought a Squid proxy, I have tested without proxy and with other proxies and it is not happening.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If the problem is the Squid proxy, then please add the proxy config to your question.

Comment: Hi @Alasdair unfortunately I don't have it :(. I will try to obtain it. I think that it could be some header that squid sends that causes the failure, but I'm not sure.